# xslt input control jquery event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt

I have this XSLT file that is loaded onto the page and then I am try to get this  jquery event to fire off. Is there anything for this to work? The function is in the `document.ready` so I am not sure why its not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/tjmcdevitt/rtxoyb57/9/

xslt

```
<div class="input-group">
     <input class="form-control" id="txtstartIpAddr" name="txtstartIpAddr" type="text" 
      maxlength="12" size="12"></input>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
 $('#txtstartIpAddr').on("input", function() {
      var dInput = this.value;
      console.log(dInput);
 });
```

Comment: What does "I have this XSLT file that is loaded onto the page" mean exactly, how/when is the XSLT applied, by the browser, automatically due to an `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction in an XML document you load into a window or frame?

Comment: Its using `inputXSL.Load` base on the tab so its not in focus at the time `document.ready` all on the same page. Is that why the event is not getting called?

Comment: I think you need to show a minimal but complete sample to allow us to tell what goes wrong.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have added a jsfiddle that I think is what I am seeing in my main project.

Comment: In that sample the input element is only added on user action so I don't see why you expect an event handler based on an element id to be hooked up when the element with that id is not yet created and is not part of the document.

Comment: Would I need to call it from the parent?

Comment: That fiddle has used some different way to attempt to hook up the event handler (`.on("input")` in your original code, `.change` in the fiddle). The fiddle also has `input id="txtIpAddress"` but tries to set up the event for `$("#txtstartIpAddr")`.

Comment: If you want to hook up the event handler to the element based on the id I think you need to do that after inserting the element into the document.